# Extract panel size from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I try to extract width and height of the panel from the `ggplot` object. What I have done so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
# Create object
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram()
# Convert the plot to a grob
gt <- ggplotGrob(p)
# Extract panel
panel <- gtable_filter(gt, "panel")
```

Now I'm stacked with extracting the correct size. Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`panel$widths` will return `1null`. That's a feature of ggplot2: the panel is sized such that it will expand to fill the available space on the viewport.